# json_encode() return nothing

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

I have a PHP script that parses an array using the json_encode() method but returns blank

The PHP Code is as follows

```
$companies = $db->getCustomerNames();
print_r($companies)
if (!empty($companies)){
$jsonstring = json_encode($companies);
echo $jsonstring ; 
}
else{
    echo 'false';
}
```

- $companies is populated and i can print it out yet

I also have a javascript that looks like this

```
jQuery.ajax({

    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost/myscript.php"
    success: function(msg) {
        companies = jQuery.parseJSON(msg);
        //DO OTHER STUFF WITH companies 
    }
});
```

- The PHP script connects to a DB and echo the JSON encoded array
- The Javascript gets the array using AJAX so i can use it's content
- When I hit http://localhost/myscript.php i get a blank page
- Works fine on my local server
- The page is hosted on Yahoo (not sure if it makes a difference)

Comment: How can `json_encode()` return that output? That's `print_r()` output.

Comment: Are you confusing `json_encode` and `json_decode`...?

Comment: Show your PHP code where you use `json_encode()` and `echo` the results

Comment: Is the requesting page on `localhost` as well?

Comment: @BlotClock You are right,  I later on noticed that i had print_r statment and removed.  Only then did i notice that json_encode() returns nothing for me.  Turns out the function is disabled on the server I am using

Comment: @Phil I have updated my question to show the code

Comment: @pekka, No, its on Yahoo and they dont support json_encode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use function_exist because on some servers json* functions could be disabled or php is configured to not use it

Comment: Spot on my friend.  The function json_encode does not exist.  Hoe silly is that of Yahoo.  Any ideas on how i can get around the problem?

Comment: I logged into yahoo CP.  Under the PHP section the version was set to PHP4,  I changed it to PHP5 and my code now works.  Thank you Evgeniy Skulditsky

Answer (score 2):

If the array is displaying like you mention in the text of your question then something is wrong. That page should be displaying something like

```
["IBM","EDS","MICROSOFT"]
```

Could you post the relevant PHP code as well please?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  It seemed that the array i was seeing earlier was a result of print_r.   Now I am not getting anything at all.  Its like as if json_encode() returns nothing.  I have edited my post to reflect the issue

Comment: @Maro You're populating `$companies` but you're checking `$customers`. Is that a typo?

Comment: yes that is a typo, The actual code has $companies all over i have updated my post with a copy paste from the actual file

Comment: @Maro so the print_r outputs an array but the json_encode does not? Can you call serialize() on the array and post the data here?

Comment: The print_r outputs the array as follows: 'Array ( [0] => aqz [1] => Bit Lounge LTD [2] => customware [3] => I AM [4] => test )'  I have tried printing outside the if statment and inside and both times worked.  Nothing prints after the encode statment.  Can you expllain to me what you mean by call serialize on the array.

Comment: @maro, you didn't paste the data :)

Comment: Hey man, I appreciate all your help,  turns out that the function does not exist on teh server or disabled.  I used function_exists and the result was not a news i wanted to hear

Comment: @maro, damn! we should have started with verision >.< From the manual `(PHP 5 >= 5.2.0, PECL json >= 1.2.0)` So, 5.2 at least :(

Answer (score 0):

Your js is right and as JohnP said when you hit http://localhost/myscript.php you should get the array displayed as ["IBM","EDS","MICROSOFT"]. Check if you have code similar to the below:

```
<?php
$a = array (0 =>'IBM' ,1=>'EDS' ,2=>'SUN' ,3=>'GOOGLE' ,4 => 'ORACLE'); 
echo json_encode($a);
?>
```

Comment: I was expecting that as well,  The funny thing is that it works fine on 2 or my local servers.  Just not on Yahoo

Answer (score 0):

First you do `print_r($companies)` then you do `echo $jsonstring;` Remove the print_r line, because ofcourse the response won't be a valid JSON string.

Also try to add `header("Content-Type: text/plain");` before you do echo and be sure to put that string before ANY output.

Comment: And it will be a blank page if you don't do javascript mastery to put that content on the page. Because AJAX itself doesn't print on the screen, but the jqXHR object holds the response. Use Firebug or Web Developer tools with Chrome and open the network tab to see if any AJAX conversation goes on and inspect the response you have recieved from your script.

Comment: I understand that.  My PHP script echos the JSON arrays, this script is called from the application via a jQuery AJAX call, which goes through the array and does stuff such as auto complete and some other validation.  This was also working fine locally, but it stopped working once I deployed to the yahoo hosted server.

Comment: The print_r is a left over debug statement from some debugging i have done after the problem surfaced and before posting the question and hence it was showing in the code above.  On removal of the debug statement I got a blank page.  Turns out, that the host had PHP4 which does not support json_encode.  After fiddling with the host control panel I was able to do an upgrade to PHP5 and the code worked fine